# How to use specific GPU device for learning in keras R?

Tags: r, keras

I`m Da-Bin.

I want to use specific GPU device for learning in keras R not python.
Because when I tried learning two program simultaneously, one program is good working but another program is not working.
I think that it seems another program is waiting until end of learning.
So, I have two GPU 1080 ti, I want use specific device for each program.
But, multi_gpu_model function use When use the more than two device, right?

If i can use the multi_gpu_model function for learning using one device.
How can I know device name for parameter "gpu=" name ?

And, how can I use the specific device for each program?

Answer (score 0):

By default gpu names are "/gpu:0", "/gpu:1" ... "/gpu:(n-1)" if you have n gpus.

You can pass a list of gpu names instead of an integer for gpus parameter of multi_gpu_model function.

Comment: Is it okay to use multi_gup_model function for only use one device? I want to use only one device at each program.

Comment: multi_gpu_model lets you select multiple gpus not a single one, write os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="1" at the start of your script and that script will only be able to see and use /gpu:1 , you could do the same for other scripts and change the number so they use different gpus.